# Attempting to place an image across the width of a screen then text underneath

Tags: android

I have an XML layout that is structured in such a way that I want to place the first image across the width of the screen and the height to automatically take the height of the width making it a squared image, then the text and other images below. On giving the width of the image to a match parent attribute, the text and images that are supposed to appear below the first image disappeared from the screen. Below is my XML layout attempt

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movieImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:src="@drawable/fruits" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    //below text is to appear beneath the first image
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
    //below layout to appear beneath the above text
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumbsupr" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/exp1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/exp2"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                    android:src="@drawable/thumbsdownr" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/exp2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img2" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/movieImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5px"
    android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/movieImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    //below text is to appear beneath the first image
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    //below layout to appear beneath the above text
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImage">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:src="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImage"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exp1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/exp2"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/exp2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exp2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img2"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Sample image
[image]